# JSON string with multiple fields to Dictionary

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to convert a JSON string like:

```
{
  "PropertyInfos": [
    {
      "Identification": {
        "IDValue": "102"
      },
      "PropertyName": "Casa Bella",
      "ManagementCompany": {
        "ManagementCompanyName": "ACME Trusts",
        "Identification": {
          "IDValue": "2"
        }
      },
      "Address": {
        "Address": "425 Slopestyle Skies Se",
        "City": "Lincoln",
        "State": "NE",
        "PostalCode": "67123",
        "Email": "test@example.com"
      }
    }
```

where there may be multiple properties.

I tried:

```
Dictionary<string, string> properties = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonproperties);
```

but it blows up at the second colon.  How do I get around this?

Comment: That's not valid json, you're missing a `]` and `}`, I believe maybe a type-o. Also with your current structure a `Dictionary<string, string>` will not work; you need to build out classes that represent your json.

Comment: This is a complex JSON schema, so it would be better to create a C# class structure that you can deserialize to rather than just loading it as a series of nested lists and dictionaries. There are tools like [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) that can help you do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize json like this

```
SomeClassName result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClassName>(jsonString);
```

using the following classes

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class SomeClassName
{
    [JsonProperty("PropertyInfos")]
    public PropertyInfo[] PropertyInfos { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("Identification")]
    public Identification Identification { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PropertyName")]
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ManagementCompany")]
    public ManagementCompany ManagementCompany { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Address")]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [JsonProperty("Address")]
    public string AddressAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("City")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("State")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PostalCode")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long PostalCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Identification
{
    [JsonProperty("IDValue")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long IdValue { get; set; }
}

public class ManagementCompany
{
    [JsonProperty("ManagementCompanyName")]
    public string ManagementCompanyName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Identification")]
    public Identification Identification { get; set; }
}

public class ParseStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue($"{value}");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        long.TryParse(reader.Value?.ToString(),  out long result);
        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }
}
```

[Documentation about serialization/deserialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

[JsonConverterAttribute info](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeClass.htm)

Comment: How do I get this to work when jsonString is an array of apartments?

Comment: it's work for json in question
`{
  "PropertyInfos": [
    { ... },
    { ... },
     --/--
    { ... }
  ]
}`

if you have array with that json - deserialize in cycle each element